# Confusion with Carnot Cycle Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, carnot-cycle

Consider two fluids $F_1$ and $F_2$ with equal volume and heat capacity as well as $T_1$ and $T_2$ respectively, whereby $T_1 > T_2$. One uses a Carnot cycle to transfer heat from $F_1$ to $F_2$ in small cycles such that the temperatures after a certain amount of cycles are equal $T_1 = T_2 = T_0$. Now, I want to find this temperature $T_0$ in terms of $T_1$, $T_2$ and $C_V$.

My confusion is that the problem requires pumping from hot to cold temperature. Isn't this a spontaneous process? How would this be different from simply putting the two fluids in direct contact and figuring out their equilibrium temperature?

Could an approach maybe be to consider the problem of pumping hot to cold like in a refrigeration process, and  then take the negative of that process?

Any hints would be appreciated!

**Edit**- Equation for Entropy:

$$\begin{align}\Delta S =& \int_{T_1}^{T_0} C_v\frac{dT}{T} + \int_{T_2}^{T_0} C_v\frac{dT}{T} \\ =&  \ C_v\ln(\frac{T_0}{T_1}) + C_v\ln(\frac{T_0}{T_2}) \\ =& \ C_v\ln(\frac{T_0^2}{T_1T_2})\end{align} 
  $$

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re asking. When one talks about “pumping” heat one is normally talking about a heat pump and heat pumps move heat from a low temperature environment to a high temperature environment or, in your case from $F_2$ to $F_1$, not the other way around. Since heat does not spontaneously go from low to high temperature, the heat pump requires work to cause the transfer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a hint.  If you just allow the fluids to equilibrate, the amount of heat that F1 loses is equal to the amount of heat that F2 gains.  But, if you run a Carnot engine between them, the amount of heat that F1 loses exceeds the amount of heat that F2 gains.  The difference is the amount of work that the Carnot engine does.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when using your hint I thought I had it figured out, but on second glance I think I dont't. What I did now was write the difference of the changes in heats $Q_1 - Q_2 = C_v(T_1-T_0) - C_v(T_2 - T_0) = W$ and tried to solve it from there. However, this seems to yield strange results. Is the approach wrong, or am I messing up somewhere?

Comment: Check your signs.  Also, you need to do an entropy balance.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am still somewhat stuck. I have found an expression for the change in entropy, but I am not really sure how to proceed from there. Could you maybe give me an idea of what the equation ,that I need to solve, is supposed to look like?

Comment: Let's see your equation for the change in entropy.

Comment: I added it as an edit to my question.

Comment: Excellent.  If the Carnot engine is operating reversibly, what does that tell you about $\Delta S$?  What does that tell you about To?

Comment: For a reversible process it should be zero, so $\Delta S = 0$, which would mean that $T_0 = \sqrt{T_1 T_2}$?

Comment: Problem solved.

Comment: @Chet Miller Sir, in my opinion the work done by carnot engine appears only when we are considering gases(with isothermal/adiabatic compression/expansion). In this case we are dealing with fluids. By using, the term "carnot engine" , i think it refers to the max output(although I know the efficiency formula holds for gases, not sure if it universally applicable for any canot engine).Also for the same reason, I think that we wouldn't consider this as a cyclic process, and hence change in entropy of system needn't be 0 as well. Could you please clarify on this and also have a look at my answer ?

Comment: @user600016  You seem to be misinterpreting the problem statement.  The two fluids F1 and F2 are no the working fluids of a Carnot engine.  They are the fluids in the two reservoirs that are used in conjunction with the Carnot engine (for which the working fluid is an ideal gas).  The Carnot engine is situated between the reservoirs F1 and F2, and receives heat from F! while discharging heat to F2 during each cycle.  This is how it accomplishes doing work.

Comment: @Chet Miller Oh. Why is my answer incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This answer is incorrect...

The efficiency of carnot engine $\eta = 1- \frac{T2}{T1} = 1 - \frac{|Q_{rejected of system}|}{|Q_{absorbed of system }|} $

$= 1- \frac{-CdT_1}{CdT_2} \implies -T1dT1= T2dT2 \implies \frac{T_1^2-T_0^2}{2}$

$=\frac{T_0^2-T_2^2}{2} \implies T_0=\sqrt{\frac{T_1^2+T_2^2}{2}}$.

Comment: With that value for the final temperature, the sum of the entropy changes of the hotter fluid and the colder fluid do not add up to zero for reversible operation (as they must).

Comment: @Chet Miller yes you are right sir thanks